# Fourier transformation of Hamiltonian with Alternate Hopping amplitude

Tags: fourier-transform, boundary-conditions

How to perform the Fourier transformation of the series: $$ \sum_{<l,m>}(-1)^{l+1}(a_{l}^{+}a_{m}+a_{l}a_{m}^{+})$$ where the sum is over the nearest neighbours (l,m), l=1 to N,and there is periodic boundary condition, $$a_{l+N}=a_{l}$$ First, I rewrite the above expression as : $$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{l,\delta}[a_{l}^{+}a_{l+\delta}+a_{l}a_{l+\delta}^{+}]$$ I am getting some form like the following:  $$\sum_{k,\delta}\frac{1}{2}[a_{k}^{+}a_{k}(e^{i.k.\delta}+e^{-i.k.\delta})]-\sum_{k,k_{1},\delta}[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{l=even}e^{-i.(k-k_{1}).r_{l}}e^{i.k_{1}.\delta}a_{k}^{+}a_{k_{1}})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\frac{N}{2}}\sum_{l=even}e^{-i.(k-k_{1}).r_{l}}e^{-i.k_{1}.\delta}a_{k}a_{k_{1}}^{+})]$$  How to proceed from here? I don't get a delta function since the sum is not over all lattice sites l. What will be the final answer?

Comment: You can double the unit cell and then Fourier transform.

Comment: This transformation is done on a ferromagnetic lattice. I don't think that is acceptable. @Meng Cheng

Comment: You can always double the unit cell. I don't know why it has anything to do with "ferromagnetic".

Comment: Any book/reference where this argument is discussed in detail would be nice and helpful. @Meng Cheng.